# How to loop through rows for data to display multiple results?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, search, display

I have searched many forums including Stack Overflow and not been able to find a solution for this that works. *Please do not mark this as duplicate.*

I have a database of users with multiple entries for certain items. The users are saved in one table ("TABLE 1") and the items are saved in another ("TABLE 2"). What I need the code to do is search TABLE 2 for user IDs that match the selected user from TABLE 1 and then for each matching entry display the item data for that row. The code I currently have is below but it is only displaying one result and then stopping. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

$queryItems = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE user_id='$results[id]'");

$itemmatch_result = mysql_fetch_array($queryitems) or die($itemmatch."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

{
    ?>

<div class="column6">

<div class="item-container">

<p class="itemname"><?php echo $itemmatch_result['item_make'] . " BRAND " . $itemmatch_result['item_type']; ?> item</p>

<p class="itemsize"><strong>Item Size:</strong> <span><?php echo $itemmatch_result['item_size']; ?></span></p>

<p class="tiresize"><strong>Item Model:</strong> <span><?php echo $itemmatch_result['item_model']; ?></span></p>

<p class="tiresize"><strong>Registered:</strong> <span><?php echo date('F jS, Y', $itemmatch_result['item_registered']); ?> AT STORE</span></p>
```

```
<span class="purchase-data">BOUGHT <?php echo date('F jS, Y', $itemmatch_result['item_bought']); ?></span>

</div>

<?php

}

unset($itemmatch_result);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through all records as long as the query is giving you the records you expect.

```
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($queryItems)) {
     echo '
          <p class.........>' . $data['item_make'] . ' BRAND .....
     ';
}
```

*Btw, you shouldn't be using mysql anymore as it's deprecated, I would suggest starting to use mysqli/pdo instead.*

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I will give this a try. RE: mysqli/pdo, I have tried converting some of this code but I keep coming up with errors that I don't know how to reconcile. Do you know of any useful resources/guides for a beginner to convert MySQL to MySQLi/PDO?

Comment: Personally I just prefer using the PHP documentation, but you can find great tutorials also if thats preferable. You can get my skype address here (http://pastebin.com/3wBhSjRM) and I can help you out if needed.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is still giving me some trouble. I've edited the code to what you see below. It's not displaying any results and just showing an error message: "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given" Any suggestions?

<?php
$queryitems = "SELECT * FROM bt_items WHERE user_id='$results[id]'";
$itemmatch_result = mysql_fetch_array($queryitems) or die($itemmatch."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($queryitems)) {
echo "This is a {$itemmatch_result['item_make']} brand {$itemmatch_result['item_type']}";
}
?>

Comment: You don't execute the query anywhere. The second line should be: $itemmatch_result = mysql_query($queryitems) or die($itemmatch."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());